# Using Web App and Salesforce API to Fill Out Reports

Tags: rest-api, salesforce1-app

I'm interested in streamlining a currently tedious process. Essentially it's a report I fill out in Salesforce that has check boxes and textareas. Will the Salesforce API allow me to access this kind of information and alter it from my web app? Thanks for any helpful input!

Comment: I wanted to add a comment someone made in the Salseforce forum: "It would, provided your salesforce edition has API access (Enterprise or above). You can have a look around here: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Integration" (- Shashank)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SF.SE Kenny. Text Areas are not supported natively in Salesforce1 Apps using standard pages. I refer you to the [Salesforce1 Mobile App Admin Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1appadmin.meta/salesforce1appadmin/) ,  the [Salesforce1 Mobile App Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/) and the [Mobile SDK Development Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/) for more. As I've not developed any custom Apps using the SDK, I can't say if they're supported using the Mobile SDK via a Flex Page and suggest you check to see. I suspect they might be as you'd have options that aren't available using standard visual force pages displayed using the Salesforce1 App UI.